# Firebase crashlystics with Smartlook SDK not reporting crash

Tags: android, gradle, crashlytics

1) I have integrated smartlook sdk in android app for screen recording.

2) After that i have integrated firbase crashlytics in same app

Now when the app crashes the screen goes black screen and app remains black instead of closing.

I have noted that 
 - If app crash without smartlook initialization app crash log is reported
 - But when smartlook is initialized, crash stop reporting on firebase

```
implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'
```

and

```
implementation('com.smartlook.recording:app:1.1.2-native')
```

Comment: We have also integrated Smartlook then Firebase Crashlytics and facing lots of libc.so related crashes. After googling we found culprit inside the Smartlook. So we decided to remove its sdk from project. review this link https://github.com/smartlook/smartlook-mobile-issue-tracker/issues/28